Stocks, Bonds, Bills, and Inflation® (SBBI®) Yearbook - replacement
One of the main aggregate datasets for historical returns on different assets classes (the Stocks, Bonds, Bills, and Inflation® (SBBI®) Yearbook) is being discontinued. Source: https://www.kroll.com/en/cost-of-capital/stocks-bonds-bills-inflation-sbbi-yearbook
For those of you who do not know this book, it literally has time-series since 1926 to 2023 for the following asset classes:

Large-Cap Stocks
Small-Cap Stocks
Long-term Corp Bonds
Long-term Gov’t Bonds
Inter-term Gov’t Bonds
U.S. Treasury Bills
Inflation

I am trying to find replacement for all of these time-series. I have a good view on what to replace most of these with:

Large-Cap Stocks: S&P 500
Small-Cap Stocks: Small cap stocks from Fama-French
Long-term Corp Bonds  ???
Long-term Gov’t Bonds 20-year U.S. government bonds
Inter-term Gov’t Bonds 5-year U.S. government bonds
U.S. Treasury Bills  1-month U.S. government t-bills
Inflation CPI

The big issue is long-term corporate bonds. It seems that the Ibbotson index for that is being discontinued. The underlying data seems to be value-weighted returns on AAA and AA corporate bonds with 20 years to maturity (or close to it).
Any private or public dataset that would allow me to replicate this?

I take the US T-Bills rate from here https://www.aqr.com/Insights/Datasets

Those are easy to get, I can get them from Fama-French or FRED too. Corporate bonds is the tricky one. But thanks!

You can get the Moody's Seasoned [US] Corporate Bond Yield since 1919:01 from FRED.
I suggest the Baa-rated series because it has long represented a larger proportion of the aggregate amount outstanding than the Aaa-rated series. It's also more volatile and less correlated with Treasury yields; particularly useful if you are trying to isolate credit risk by taking the approximate spread to Treasuries. If you prefer the Aaa series just change the last three letters of the URL to 'AAA'.
As to the "long-term" characteristic of your original series: if that meant anything longer-dated than T-bills, this series should suffice.

Unfortunately (without additional data such as duration, etc.) it is difficult to go from a yield time series to a time series of returns.
